# How to fix "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"/properly load the dataset?

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm trying to help someone with their r code. As far as I can tell we're trying to load an unemployment dataset, set it to a variable, then use the summary() + the lm() function to display the data? I'm not entirely sure as I don't know R and the assignment is in Russian. However, we can't seem to use the $ as listed in the notes. What I've seen is you cant use $ on an array/vector. What would be the proper way to run this function?

I can use getElement(variable, position) and get a number back. Hopefully meaning we've loaded the dataset at least.

```r
library(lmtest)
library(zoo)
df=unemployment
help(unemployment)
df=read.csv("unemployment",sep="\t",dec=".",header=TRUE)
un=unemployment[,1]
exp=unemployment[,5]
summary(lm(df$un~df$exp_1))
```

What I'm assuming is happening:

we load the libraries containing the unemployment dataset.

We assign df to the dataset.
We're reading the file for some reason?

We set 2 variables, then we try to use summary and lm to display some kind of model.

Clearly the error is in the assignment somewhere or the order. Thanks.

Comment: Is there an error message from the `read.csv` line? Does `str(df)` show a data.frame with the expected columns?

Comment: If the goal is the regression model in the last line, you can remove lines 2, (4), 6, 7. And you should use either line 3 or line 5 to create `df`.

Comment: As far as I can tell str(df) does not showa data.frame, from previous questions I did see that I needed a data frame. I was just unsure of how to create one.
I'll also try removing these redundant lines. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Data set `unemployment` is a time series matrix which is not data.frame. `$` is only supported by a list (data.frame included).

To access column of a matrix use this:

```
unemployment[,"UN"]
```

or similar to what your provides, try:

```
library(lmtest)
library(zoo)
df=unemployment
help(unemployment)

df <- as.data.frame(df) # convert to data.frame
head(df)                # observe df
summary(lm(df$UN~df$x)) # call with right column names
```

Comment: Normally the last line would be written as `summary(lm(UN ~ x, df))` .